# Modify original windows window

Tags: windows, winapi, shell-extensions

Is it possible somehow modifiy original windows window programatically? For example, adding some buttons or similar things?

Comment: What do you mean by "original windows window"?

Comment: for example control panel window or documents window

Comment: some things in windows are customizable, obviously. which one are you talking about?

Comment: @Rampage So, to be clear, you would like to add some controls to the Windows Control Panel or Windows Explorer? What do you want these controls to do? I ask because there are standard ways to extend the shell and it's always best to take that approach if possible.

Comment: The "Original Windows Window" http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4e/Windows1.0.png

Comment: So, my first goal is to change windows 7 default energy scheme choosing window to display some other informations. What approach should i use?

Comment: @Rampage, for example? Change the title of the window?